# Upper extension method in linq to NHibernate

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate

I would like to use the Upper extension method which is declared on the IDbMethods interface against Sql Server 2008.

The extension methods are defined in NHibernate.Linq.SqlClient.SqlClientExtensions

I understand that this will translate to UPPER() on sql server.

However I can not figure out how to get an implementation of IDbMethods so that I can use the extension method.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this problem?

Comment: No the work around was to not use linq to NHibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use IDbMethods. Just use `YourStringProperty.ToUpper()` and the provider will map it.

Comment: No there is an open issue about that. It throws an exception, index out of range or something. http://216.121.112.228/browse/NHLQ-66

Comment: Have you tried using the NEW Linq provider (NH 3.x) instead of downvoting people that help you?

Comment: As far as I can tell NH 3.x is not released. Source forge does not have any packages for it. This is to be used in production software so a unreleased version is not good enough, The bug is still open so I have no reason to believe it is fixed.  If you don't want to be down voted then answer the question, which is about IDbMethods.

Comment: +1 Come on, Daniel, it was a good faith effort to help. Try to be more discerning in your voting.